# Page.OnNavigatedTo doesn't get called in Windows Store app

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a Windows Store mess around app. I added a Basic Page and it added the Common classes, such as LayoutAwarePage.

But Page.OnNavigatedTo doesn't get called when an app starts. The MSDN doc says:

> Invoked when the Page is loaded and becomes the current source of a
>   parent Frame

Which happens during launch. I discovered this when LoadState wasn't being called.

Rick Barraza uses LoadState, which is called by OnNavigatedTo, in his demo:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Migrating-apps-from-Windows-Phone-to-Windows-8/Binding-the-Interface-in-Windows-Store-apps#time=2m50s

I know something is broken because now that I've added some navigation buttons, the OnNavigatedFrom *is* called but falls over because _pageKey is null since it wasn't set by OnNavigatedTo.

I actually am pretty stuck. This is a failing in Microsoft's native Page class, but clearly I'm the only person to have this issue and its 100% discoverable. Odd.

**Update 1**

I added a new Grid App project and that works. The Common stuff is all there as standard but it does differ from the Common stuff that's written when you add a Basic Page to an empty app.

I will try and repro this from a fresh empty app.

**Update 2**

Well, I give up. A new Blank App and adding a new Blank Page is fine. I'll just copy and paste my page over and pretend it never happened.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it was due to the presence of an empty override of OnNavigateTo in the basic pages I've added.

```
public sealed partial class MvvmView1
    {
        public MvvmView1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
        /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dunno if it was my cause but a useful answer +1

Answer (score 1):

In order for OnNavigatedTo to get called, your Frame must call its Navigate method.

```
Frame localFrame = this.MyFrame; //this assumes MyFrame is Frame that exists in xaml and has a name 

localFrame.Navigate(new myPage());
```

If you are using content injection

```
localFrame.Content  = new myPage();
```

The OnNavigatedTo event of myPage will not fire, because the page is loaded only, not navigated to.

Comment: Useful to know, but this is a standard templated app, so I have 'if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage1), args.Arguments))' in the App.xaml.cs which works - but the OnNavigatedTo is not called. Shame I don't have a diffing tool because I now have two 'identical' projects where one works and one doesn't.